# Array Pattern using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array: `Myarray=[1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0]`

I want to display the elements of the array in the pattern 1,0,1,0..

I tried to set a flag:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  if (myArray[i] == flag) {
    newArray = newArray + myArray[i];
    if (flag == 0)
      flag = 1;
    else
      flag = 0;
  }
```

But the problem is the mismatched elements are not showing in output.

Any Idea? Thanks.

Comment: I don't quite understand the question, but I fixed the formatting so someone else may be able to help you.

Comment: I didn't really get it. Isn't your purpose just output the pattern and neglect the mismatched elements?

Comment: Please explain your problem better. It makes no sense right now.

Comment: *flag* is not initialised, so `myArray[i] == flag` can never be true.

Comment: what pattern do you exactly want? can you give us the full desired output using your example array (Myarray). Your question is not clear.

Comment: What do you mean by display the elements?  Are you just trying to sort the elements in a toggled pattern and assign them to the newArray?

Comment: @RobG: isn't flag set each iteration? (it would only miss the first, and 0==false)

Comment: @dandavis the flag will be "undefined" if not instantiate properly. It will never enter the if condition and be assigned a proper value

Comment: ohh, err, yeah, i was confused by the braces, or lack thereof rather. so the snip is a syntax error.

Comment: @dandavis— *flag* is not initialised, so it's value is *undefined*. *myArray[i]* is either 0 or 1, so the expression `myArray[i] == flag` is always false and the block that sets the value of *flag* is not entered.

Comment: Is your intention to remove consecutive equal values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generating a *new Array* of *1, 0, 1, 0, ...* with *length* equal to `myArray.length` can be done in one line with [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
var newArr = myArray.map(function (e, i) {return 1 - (i % 2);});
```

However, it may be more efficient to use a loop;

```
var newArr = [],
    i = myArray.length;
while (i-- > 0)
    newArr[i] = 1 - (i % 2);

newArr; // [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

---

If you want to filter out consecutive repeating items, you can use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with a variable outside the filter function to remember what you last saw

```
var newArray = (function () {
    var last;
    return myArray.filter(function (e) {
        var t = last;
        last = e;
        if (t === last)
            return false;
        return true;
    });
}());
```

Or again in a loop

```
var newArr = [],
    last,
    i;
for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; ++i)
    if (last !== myArray[i]) {
        last = myArray[i];
        newArr.push(last);
    }

newArr; // [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

Comment: curious: how would a loop be more efficient ?

Comment: In _JavaScript_ you get a function overhead for each time you invoke a function, and here we invoke it `myArray.length` times

Comment: I thought about that and it works here yes, but decided against it because `b-1` is not always the same as the `e` of the last `true` return, meaning it would only work on this specifically.

Comment: @blex: do you know a lot about perf? why do loops consistently run 50%-400% faster than the filter() on the fiddle, but when i paste the same code into fiddle's/anyone's devtools console and run, the filter() part  is WAY faster (~12X) ? https://jsfiddle.net/v073eya2/

Comment: @blex: thanks for the follow up, much obliged! much.

Comment: @blex open your console on this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/01v4rbaL/ On my machine (running Google Chrome) loop comes out as just over 4x faster. However, pasting the same code in console, filter comes out as 7x faster. This leads me to believe that there is some behind-the-scenes things going on, but on a page where the script isn't injected the loop should be faster -- **edit** wrapping as an IIFE sees the loop win again when in console http://jsfiddle.net/01v4rbaL/1/

Comment: can anyone explain why an IIFE radically affects perf? or why the console runs different than the page?

Comment: @dandavis may be something related to how console does weird stuff itself, putting in an IIFE moves the code invocation into the global space? See the weirdness of the console by running a function like this `(function trace() {
    var fn = trace;
    while (fn.caller) console.log(fn = fn.caller);
}());`

Answer (score 0):

Just initialize newArray to the first element of your Array then enter the for-loop checking if the next value is not equal to the last element of new array. Your code will look something like:

```
newArray[0]=myArray[0];
for (var i = 1; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    if(newArray[i-1]!=myArray[i]) {
         newArray.push(myArray[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pulling only elements that match a pattern:

```
var a   = [1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0],
    pat = [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1],
    matched = a.map(function(a1, idx) { return a[idx] === pat[idx] ? a1 : null } );

console.log(matched); // [1, 0, null, null, null, null, 1, 0, null]
```